# Конвертация строки в дату

Tags: java

```
DateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);

private JFormattedTextField product_in_date = new JFormattedTextField(date_format);

try {
    listsShield.getStorelist()
    .add(
         new StoreList().greateStoreListIn(
             listsShield.getStorelist().size(),
             (String) product_name.getSelectedItem(),
             product_articul.getText(),
             product_specefication.getText(),
             date_format.parse(product_in_date.getText()), 
             Integer.parseInt(product_in_count.getText())
        )
   );

} catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
cleareTextField();

try {
    inFile.writeToFileStore();
} catch (IOException e1) {

}
```

Проблема, что при записи в лист парсер почему то формат переводит в какой то другой формат, и всегда в него записывается в формате и значениями Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 AMT 2015.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Этой строкой Вы указываете где в Вашей строке будут располагаться части даты. Для парсинга.

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
          .format(date_format.parse("12/30/2015")));
```

А эта строка форматирует дату в нужный Вам формат. И будет возвращена строка.

Comment: Если ответ решает проблему, пожалуйста, отметьте его зелёной галочкой.